# ColdFusion 9 Virtual File System and Clustering

Tags: coldfusion, cluster-computing, vfs

Does the VFS work in a cluster scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not look like it. The docs on [GetVFSMetaData](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WS2c2b6b5d2efbc2ce-731e5f6a122ff1509d6-8000.html) only list RAM and I have not seen anything that discusses calling to another server's VFS.

Comment: Cool, thats what I thought.

Thanks!